# Can Android app run without being launched at least once?

Tags: applications, services, auto-start

As much as I know, most apps won't ever start, unless you launch them at least once (even if they have a background service).

But what about those, that for example, have the Receive Intent Boot Successfull in their Manifest? Will that be enough to launch their code?

Comment: You might want to take a look at my answer to a very similar question: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/107276/86358. Basically said: Yes if designed *correctly* apps may launch services or itself right after their installation.

Comment: I highly doubt its possible to be done RIGHT AFTER the installation, unless it's possible to receive an intent after a Boot Complete, and then run

Comment: *Right after* installation is very unlikely (unless you do an update). But there is the possibility to start by receiving an intent like ACTION_USER_PRESENT (sent whenever the device gets unlocked), ACTION_SCREEN_ON (when you turn on the screen and are able to use it) as well as ACTION_SCREEN_OFF (when you lock your phone for instance). All those intents can be received without being run *once*.

Comment: So you the final decision is that an app can only run, if it has a Broadcast Receiver in the Manifest? And it doesn't have to be launched at least once in order for this Broadcast Receiver to receive Intents?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea behind manifest intents: even if the app is not running it can receive an event intent and act on that without continuously running and probably wasting system resources.

Comment: Why should *right after installation* be unlikely, if the app registers for the `PACKAGE_INSTALLED` broadcast? ;)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Android apps can start background services after system boot or intent received.
There are xposed modules (like [defim's Boot manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.defim.apk.bootmanager) or Receiver stop) that can prevent this behavior.

Comment: Is there some list of the possible Intents that could be received from an app, that could cause it's launch, even without being opened at least once?

Comment: Please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031740/where-is-the-all-android-broadcast-intent-list

Answer (score -1):

Impossible, you must launch atleast once after installing.

Comment: source or something please?

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong. The principle of apps like [Plan B](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.lookout.labs.planb) or [Android Lost](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.androidlost) is based exactly on that: you install the apps remotely (via GPlay's Web interface), and then can control your "lost device" remotely – not even a reboot is required. So if you were correct, those apps would not work. The apps' ratings suggest something else ;)